# Dealing with automatic adding scrollbars

Tags: apache-flex, scrollbar, sizing

I have such problem: I'm creating a container and it's content at runtime. Here's a rough structure:

--VBox

----Form

-------FormItem

...

-------FormItem

----ControlBar

I have fixed maxHeights for the `form` container to keep it in bounds of screen. But when I get vertical scrollbar, the horisontal also appears (seems like it's not enough place for this VScrollBar).

To escape this problem, I've created a listener for horisontal scroll appearing, so if it appears, I'll increase container a bit, so it would feet the other scrollbar normally:

```
form.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, function(event:Event):void{
if(event.target is HScrollBar){
    while(form.horizontalScrollBar && form.horizontalScrollBar.visible && !(form.width > form.maxWidth)){
        form.width += 10;
        form.validateDisplayList();
    }
}
});
```

I've tried also `validateNow`and other similar methods. What I have here:
1. The `HScrollBar` is being added.
2. We increase a bit the width of container, so it disappears.
3. When it disappears, the validating throws the null-pointer exception when it tries to measure the non-existing scrollbar. I've also tried to add `validateProperties` before validation, but it didn't worked either.

Can anyone help to get rid of this annoying scroll? :)

Comment: Have you or have you not set the horizontalScrollPolicy on your component, and if so, to what value?

Comment: horizontalScrollPolicy also as verticalScrollPolicy wasn't set explicitly. So they should be set to auto, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is - if your scrollPolicy is set to `auto` Flex does not take scroll dimensions into consideration while calculating layout. So when scroll appears it is displayed over the content that it's already there. And when the content is hidden by the scroll a horizontal scroll appears so all content can be accessed via scrolling. The way I usually deal with that is to always set `paddingRight` (or `right` when parent is `Canvas`) style property to 20 (scroll usual width is 16) so when the scroll appears it doesn't overlap anything.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I've tried your solution, but it aint gonna work for my case *sigh*. Anyways, thanks a lot for a tip!

Comment: Ok, so what about listening for VScrollBar added event (instead of HScrollBar) and changing appropriate style in a handler. You will have to listen for removed event as well.